# how to unit test a parse method which is accepting a long string argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have to test a method which is accepting a long string as argument separated by blank spaces  . this method just parse them and returns an string array. the order of the argument is fixed since this coming from some library call which i don't have access. I am looking for some approach as to how to proceed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to split a string separated by spaces ?

Comment: i want to write a unit test for this function which is already doing this\

Comment: You can use Mockito to test your logic in your class. You don't have to access the 3rd party library. Check it [here](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: well i can make up a long string argument , that's not the problem . i am looking for some ideas as to how unit test this method

Comment: @curious I don't get it any more. What is the problem in your case? Existence of a 3rd party library? A long string argument? What is your aim to test your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the behavior you want to test and then write those tests.

For example, I would test:

- What happens if I pass in null?
- What happens if I pass in an empty string?
- What happens if there are leading or trailing spaces?
- What happens if the string only has spaces?
- What happens if there's just a single element in the string?
- Happy path

Answer (score 3):

what you need is something like.

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
  //given
  String arg = "1 2 5";
  //when
  String[] actual = yourFunction(arg);
  //then
  org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(actual, new String[]{"1","2","5"});
}
```

Please read some tutorials on JUnit testing